Jest Test: Getting Undefined for Component State After Mocking FileReader
I'm currently writing unit tests for an Angular component that processes a JSON file upload. In my test, I'm trying to mock the FileReader to simulate reading a JSON file, but I'm getting undefined for the component's state properties after invoking the uploadFile method.
Here's the relevant portion of my test:

it('should validate and load a supported JSON file', () => {
    const mockFile = new File(['[{"column1":"value1"}]'], 'test.json', { type: 'application/json' });

    const fileSpyReader = jest.spyOn(FileReader.prototype, 'readAsText').mockImplementation(function (this: FileReader) {
        this.onload?.({ target: { result: '[{"column1":"value1"}]' } } as ProgressEvent<FileReader>);
    });


    component.uploadFile(mockFile);


    expect(fileSpyReader).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockFile);

    
    expect(component.isUploadFailed).toBe(false);
    expect(component.uploadError).toBeUndefined();
    expect(component.fileContent).toEqual([{ column1: 'value1' }]); 


    expect(component.totalRecords).toBe(1); 

    fileSpyReader.mockRestore();
});

Here's a version of the uploadFile method in my component:
uploadFile(file: IFilePath): void {
    const fileReader = new FileReader();

    fileReader.onload = () => {
        const fileContents = fileReader.result;
        let data = [];
        const errors = [];

        try {
            data = JSONBig.parse(fileContents); 
        } catch (error) {
            //Some code
        }

        this.fileContent = data;
        this.totalRecords = data.length;
    };

    fileReader.readAsText(file);
}


I have mocked the readAsText method to invoke onload directly with a valid JSON string and verified the mock call but I don't know if there's something I'm missing. I'm still new to this so any help would be appreciated.
